# Libraries/options for calculating second-order ODE in C++ (Visual Studio), based on MATLAB prototype?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio

Github repo: https://github.com/armstrongc93/2dof_vibration/

I have prototyped and validated the math for a 2 degree of freedom vibration analysis in MATLAB, and now need to run it using C++ for an app. I know this is not a trivial task, but it is fairly simple in terms of actual calculations. I'm just not sure of what to look for in a library.

I have looked at Armadillo, odeint and am currently using Eigen for part of the script (calculate natural frequencies). The documentation is a bit hard to follow, so I'm not sure if the answer is staring me in the face. The current MATLAB script I need to work into C++ is as follows (everything except the t and y variables in the anonymous function are defined numerical values, these are user inputs in the C++ script):

```
% Define parameters & display
m = 1000; % [kg]
J = 800; % [kg*m^2]
k_f = 20000; % [N/m]
k_r = 25000; % [N/m]
l1 = 1.0; % [m]
l2 = 1.5; % [m]
c_f = 1000; % [N*s/m]
c_r = 1000; % [N*s/m]

% Initial conditions and time
IC = [0.1 0 0 0]; % [x x' theta theta']
time = [0 5]; % [s]
fprintf('The input parameters are:\n m =%5d kg\n J =%5d kg*m^2\n',...
 m, J)
fprintf(' kf = %5d N/m\n kr = %5d N/m\n L1 = %3.1f m\n L2 = %3.1f
m\n',...
 k_f, k_r, l1, l2)
fprintf(' cf = %3.1f N*s/m\n cr = %3.1f N*s/m\n x(0) = %3.1f
m\n',c_f,...
 c_r, IC(1))
fprintf(' timespan = 0-%g s\n',time(2))

% Determine radial frequency & y parameters
vel = 10; % [m/s]
L = 0.5; % [m]
A = 0; % [m], =0 for unforced conditions
h = A/2; % [m]
radFreq = (2*pi*vel)/L; % [rad/s]
fprintf('\n')
fprintf('The velocity of the vehicle is: %g m/s\n', vel)

% Solve 4 coupled ODE's
[t,sltn]=ode45(@(t,y)coupledEqtns(t,y,m,J,k_f,k_r,l1,l2,c_f,c_r,...
 radFreq,A,L),time,IC);

% Plot results
plot(t,sltn(:,1),t,sltn(:,3)) % Plot x and theta
title('Displacement and Pitch vs. Time')
xlabel('Time [s]')
ylabel('Amplitude')
legend('Displacement [m]','Pitch [rad]','location','NorthEast')
% Determine maximum values
maximumPitch = max(sltn(:,3));
maximumDisplacement = max(sltn(:,1));

% Display results
fprintf('The distance between bumps is: %3.2f m, and the height is:
%3.3f m\n'...
 ,L,h)
fprintf('The maximum pitch of the vehicle is: %5.4E rad\n',
maximumPitch)
fprintf('The maximum bounce of the vehicle is: %5.4E m\n',...
 maximumDisplacement)
```

It is calling the following "coupledEqtns" file:

```
function firstODE = coupledEqtns(t,y,m,J,kf,kr,L1,L2,cf,cr,radFreq,A,L)

% Function determines first order ODE equations from second order
firstODE = [y(2);
 (1/m)*(-(cf+cr)*y(2)-(kf+kr)*y(1)-(cr*L2-cf*L1)*...
 y(4)-(kr*L2-kf*L1)*y(3)+kf*A*sin((radFreq)*t)+kr*A*sin((radFreq)...
 *t-(2*pi*(L1+L2))/L));
 y(4);
 (1/J)*(-(cf*L1^2+cr*L2^2)*y(4)-(kf*L1^2+kr*L2^2)*y(3)-(cr*L2-cf*...
 L1)*y(2)-(kr*L2-kf*L1)*y(1)+kr*L2*A*sin((radFreq)*t-
(2*pi*(L1+L2))/L)...
 -kf*L1*A*sin((radFreq)*t))];
end
```

The anonymous function is definitely what is tripping me up the most here, but this is all the math that is needed to be done. I have not used C++ for anything other than basic operations so this is definitely a bit of a challenge for me. Any and all suggestions are welcome!

The c++ code (from MSVS) is currently as follows for implementation of odeint; I am now getting a subscript error:

Class def:

```
 typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

class coupledODE : public Vehicle, public Road
{
    public:
        void operator()(state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, double t)
        {
            dxdt[0] = x[2];
            dxdt[1] = (1 / mass)*(-(damping_f + damping_r)*x[2] - (stiffness_f + stiffness_r)*x[1] - (damping_r*rearLength - damping_f*frontLength)*x[4] - (stiffness_r*rearLength - stiffness_f*frontLength)*x[3] + stiffness_f*A*sin((radFreq)*t) + stiffness_r*A*sin((radFreq)*t - (2 * pi*(frontLength + rearLength)) / L));
            dxdt[3] = x[4];
            dxdt[4] = (1 / inertia)*(-(damping_f*pow(frontLength, 2) + damping_r*pow(rearLength, 2))*x[4] - (stiffness_f*pow(frontLength, 2) + stiffness_r*pow(rearLength, 2))*x[3] - (stiffness_r*rearLength - stiffness_f*frontLength)*x[2] - (stiffness_r*rearLength - stiffness_f*frontLength)*x[1] + stiffness_r*rearLength*A*sin((radFreq)*t - (2 * pi*(rearLength + frontLength)) / L) - stiffness_f*frontLength*A*sin((radFreq)*t));
        }
};
```

Odeint implementation:

```
    state_type x(4);
    x[0] = car.x_init1;
    x[1] = car.x_init2;
    x[2] = car.x_init3;
    x[4] = car.x_init4;

    const double timeStep = car.dt;
    double tStart = car.t0;
    double t = tStart;
    double tEnd = car.tf;

    // Initialize odeint
    runge_kutta4<state_type>rk4;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (tStart - tEnd) / timeStep; ++i, t += timeStep)
    {
        rk4.do_step(coupledODE(), x, t, timeStep);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, let me upload the rest of it. The firstODE is a vector of numbers, there are no symbolic vectors/variables in the code

Comment: Ok so you are really asking about https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html

Comment: and you can replace the ode45 line by  `[t,sltn]=ode45(@myfunc,time,IC)` with at the end of file  `function                 r=myfunc(t,y) 
       r = coupledEqtns(t,y,m,J,k_f,k_r,l1,l2,c_f,c_r, radFreq,A,L);
end` I'm not sure what you want then. There are not so many C++ versatile solvers (as Matlab's one) so try and see ?

Comment: Specifically I am asking about the anonymous function. So, I suppose the best approach would be to define the two functions that I need (myfunc & coupleEqtns) then just play with ODE solvers until I find one robust enough to do this?

Comment: odeint should really work for this kind of problem. You can try to use simply the integrate() method. It is a dopri5 solver with adaptive step size control and dense output.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement odeint here; how would integrate work for this problem?

Comment: @headmyshoulder I will update it this afternoon

Comment: @headmyshoulder I have updated the post to reflect how I have tried implementing

Comment: In principle the code looks good. Can you add the error message (or the relevant part of it)?

Comment: Yes! I'm not getting an error anymore, per say. The issue I am running into now is passing the values from the other classes into the coupledEqtn class. Everything builds fine, but because there are no values associated with the ODE object in the functor, I don't get any values. I have posted a link to my Github, where the code is stored.